# Losing scripts when importing a Postman collection into Hoppscotch

Tags: hoppscotch

When I import a collection from Postman into Hoppscotch all Pre-request and Test scripts seem to be gone. Does anyone know if there is a way to save them?
I do export a collection as json from Postman, then select "import from Postman" in Hoppscotch. Maybe there is a different better way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it seems [Postman scripts](https://learning.postman.com/docs/writing-scripts/script-references/test-examples/) and [Hoppscotch scripts](https://docs.hoppscotch.io/documentation/features/scripts) are incompatible so far.

There is [an issue](https://github.com/hoppscotch/hoppscotch/issues/2904) about this, and a workaround to import scripts if by any chance you self-host your instance.

It would nice though if the script would be imported during the import, and that Hoppscotch supports postman API, even though unofficially if they want to avoid a copycat infringement.